# react-router render is not working; routing is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm making wizard form in react
and have got a problem with routing
page routing is like this

home -> wizard form(step1) -> step2 ->step3..

```
<Route
 path="/startAProgram/step1"
 exact
 render={() => <StartAProgram />}
/>

//app.js
//There are many routes in app.js and one of routes is StartAProgram(wizard form)
```

```
function StartAProgram() {
  return (
    <WrapperDiv>
      <Stepper />
      <ProgramName /> {/* this is step 1 */}
      <Router>
        {/* <Route path="startAProgram/step1" render={() => <ProgramName />} /> */}
        <Switch>
          <Route
            path="startAProgram/step2"
            exact
            render={() => <SetTargets />}
          />
          <Route
            path="startAProgram/step3"
            render={() => <ParticipationGuidelines />}
          />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </WrapperDiv>
  );
}
```

- react-router-dom version:^5.2.0

```
function ProgramName() {
  const programName = useSelector((state) => state.programName);

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: programName,
  });

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleOnSubmit = (data) => {
    sessionStorage.setItem('programName', Object.values(data));
    dispatch(submitStep1(data));
    history.push('./step2');
    console.log('next~');
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleOnSubmit)}>
      <Text size={30} weight={800} mb={10}>
        Step 1. Program name
      </Text>
      <label htmlFor="programName">
        Program Name
        <input
          name="programName"
          {...register('programName', { required: 'fill out!' })}
        />
        <ErrorMessage errors={errors} name="programName" as="p" />
      </label>
      <Button type="submit">next</Button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

It would be Step2 if the form validation is successful but Step2 component rendering is not working currently.
Page Step 1 is rendering well, but it is not letting me render step 2 and more.
Anyone can solve this problem?

Comment: What specific versions of `react` and `react-router` or `react-router-dom` are installed? You can check by running `npm list react react-router react-router-dom`. You also seem to be rendering a router in the middle of your routing code. Is `StartAProgram` the `StartAProgramPresenter` component? Can you edit to include a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] that includes how you are setting up all your routing?

Comment: react-router-dom version is ^5.2.0. and StartAProgramPresenter is the same as StartAProgram component.

Comment: And the `react` version and related routing/app code?

Comment: react version is 17 and there are many routing in app.js and one of routes is StartAProgram component.

Comment: We don't necessarily need to see all the routes, but it would be nice to see where/how the `"/startAProgram/step1"` route is rendered, all the way up to the root router component, and any components rendering links or buttons to effect navigation actions.

Comment: I added more details on the post. please check it out and let me know if you need more!

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

`StartAProgram` is rendering these other routes, so when you navigate to one of those routes, the route rendering `StartAProgram` is no longer matched and those other routes you are linking to are no longer mounted.

## Solution

Make the root stepper route path more generic so it can match rendering any of the steps.

```
<Route path="/startAProgram" component={StartAProgram} />
```

Then refactor `StartAProgram` to render `ProgramName` back on a `".../step1"` path. Remove the extra `Router` component, you only need one router per app.

```
function StartAProgram() {
  return (
    <WrapperDiv>
      <Stepper />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/startAProgram/step1" component={ProgramName} />
        <Route path="/startAProgram/step2" component={SetTargets} />
        <Route
          path="/startAProgram/step3"
          component={ParticipationGuidelines}
        />
      </Switch>
    </WrapperDiv>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-router-render-is-not-working-routing-is-not-working]

When nesting descendent routes it is a common pattern to use the `useRouteMatch` hook to dynamically build relative paths.

```
import { Switch, Route, useRouteMatch } from 'react-router-dom';

function StartAProgram() {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <WrapperDiv>
      <Stepper />
      <Switch>
        <Route path={`${path}/step1`} component={ProgramName} />
        <Route path={`${path}/step2`} component={SetTargets} />
        <Route path={`${path}/step3`} component={ParticipationGuidelines} />
      </Switch>
    </WrapperDiv>
  );
}
```

This is helpful/useful if you need to move the `StartAProgram` component around onto a different path, the links and routes from here work relative to the current location.